# Diffrenece between two pl/sql with cursor for update (oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, cursor, oracle19c

I got this working code:

```
declare
 cursor c1 is select * from a.testA;
 testA_record a.testA%rowtype;
begin
 
  open c1;
    loop fetch c1 into testA_record; 
      exit when c1%notfound;
      
      update a.testA set colA = 100;
    
    end loop;
  close c1;
  
end;
```

Then made litte changes:

```
declare
 cursor c1 is select * from a.testA k for update;
 testA_record a.testA%rowtype;
begin
 
  open c1;
    loop fetch c1 into testA_record; 
      exit when c1%notfound;      
      
       update k set colA = 100 where current of c1;--without this line code is running
    
    end loop;
  close c1;
  
end;
```

And getting error: ORA-00942.

What is wrong or missing?

Comment: `update k` should be replaced with `update a.testA`

Comment: 'k for update' => it's necessary to add this to cursor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
update k set colA = 100 where current of c1;
```

raised ORA-00942 (table or view doesn't exist).

As the only table involved here is `k`, I'd say that there's no table named `k` available to you. Either you don't own it, there's no (public) synonym, ...

Should've probably been

```
update a.testA set ...
```

Comment: I thought that it will be 'k' take from cursor "k for update"

Comment: You thought wrong.